# Stuck on We're removing your app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, error, app

I was deploying my app and after 20 minutes I canceled the deploy by hitting AltGr + PauseBreak or Crtl + PauseBreak (don't remeber).

Now in SharePoint it just says We're removing your app... for about 1 hour. Has someone had this problem or know how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Not much of a solution, but I've had this issue before.  I'd change the app's guid, and continue working.  The next day it'd usually be removed, and I'd revert the guid back to what it was.

Comment: ithink in this case, wait is better method or 2nd thing open a service ticket with 365 support team

Comment: It's gone took about 2 hours

Comment: I have an impression that removing a CUSTOM app may take up to 24hours, but I cannot find any confirmation in the articles. It may be related to updates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn265910(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Same here.
SP Online is very very unstable. If something like this happens, you have to recreate your site collection or you have to change the name and GUID of your app and install it again. But if you have content in app parts for example, you will lose it.

Comment: i have same issue its been 5 hours now ..... nothing working

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same issue and steps below fixed it for me:

SharePoint stuck removing the app because it can't find app package
because deployment was cancelled.

Upload app package to App Packages and try to remove app again.

Comment: Much appreciate it ! It worked , i was waiting for 40 minutes until i tried out your solution

Comment: this works if its a custom app, but what if the app was from SharePoint Store? Like Adobe sign app is stuck on removing and cant figure how to remove it.